# BCmath php 64bit

Tags: php, 64-bit, bcmath

i'm using BCmath to do math with 64 bit unsigned integers, i want to make a bcmath-object to a normal int (high, low part) how can i achieve that ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Doesn't bcmath do it's math with string representations of numbers rather than 64-bit integers (signed or unsigned)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inbuilt BCMath functions don't deal with BCMath objects as such, they just process on strings to achieve arbitrary precision computation.  So you can convert back to a native php int with a normal cast.

```
$val = (int) bcmod( bcpow( "9392", "394" ), "100" );
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php, method signatures are

```
string bcmod ( string $left_operand , string $modulus )
string bcpow ( string $left_operand , string $right_operand [, int $scale ] )
```

Comment: $res['high'] = (int) bcdiv($ad_t, "4294967296");
            $res['low'] = (int) bcmod($ad_t, "4294967296");